# Is it possible to configure a SATA RAID 1 hardware array on X570 without losing data?

Tags: raid, amd-ryzen

So i basically got a 2nd identical SATA HDD to the one i use to store my bulk data (note OS/system drive is on a different nvme m.2 sdd).

Is it possible to configure a RAID 1 array with the new HDD on X570 bios without losing the existing data on the current HDD?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge when creating a new RAID array, all of the disks must be formatted together, meaning that the old disk would need to be formatted and the data would be lost. Windows does have built in software features which allow you to create a RAID 1, RAID 5 and RAID 0 array. It also allows for a spanned array, but that is not really used very often. RAID 5 would offer the best performance and reliability, allowing for full recovery of data lost, depending on the size of the array.

Using Disk Management to create the new disk as a mirror of the old disk would be the best way to do it without losing any data, as Windows generally tries to create the mirror while preserving the users data. Obviously it can fail, but it tries at least. I have used Windows to create a mirror of a disk, and it did not go terribly well for me. I was trying to create a mirror of a partition with different sized disks though, so your experience will probably differ from mine.

Comment: i think i came up with a solution:

1) Install new drive and initialize it (only this one)

2) Create an array to this drive. I don't know if it will allow RAID 1 option with only 1 drive but it should allow the RAIDABLE option which should allow conversion to RAID 1 later

3) Go into windows and copy all data from old drive to new drive (preferably copy the whole partition using a partition manager)

4) Go into bios and initialize the old drive and add it to the existing array

5) It should start to mirror the data now, or allow you to do it after you convert RAIDABLE to RAID 1.